# How to keep Python application alive and listening to ActiveMQ?

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp

I'm new to Python so maybe this is a trivial question, but I haven't been able to find the answer I'm looking for yet.

I'm working on running different Python applications on data using a message broker (ActiveMQ) and STOMP. I'm able to build and run a single application that sends a message to a channel it's subscribed to and triggers a listener method. Now I'm trying to send a message from one Python application ("sender") to a queue and subscribe to it from a different Python application ("receiver"). However, after setting up the connection/subscriber in the receiver how do I keep it alive and listening for a message from the sender for an indefinite amount of time?

Other threads I've found mention using `sleep` statements which does technically prevent the application from exiting, but it also blocks the application so it doesn't do anything either.

Comment: Check this out https://isurunuwanthilaka.medium.com/get-into-mqtt-in-2-minutes-python-docker-5d4e8b55cf1c

Comment: What protocol and client implementation are you using?

Comment: @JustinBertram hmm not sure what you mean by client implementation, but using Stomp protocol to an ActiveMQ container.

Comment: The "client implementation" would be whatever you're using to send & receive messages via STOMP (e.g. stomp.py, stompest, stompy, stomper, etc.). I assume you're using a client here and not actually manually constructing the STOMP frames and manipulating TCP sockets.

Comment: Asking about Docker is a Red Herring. What you need instead is a Python program that does what you want to do. The fact that it's executed insider of a Docker container is irrelevant. It could have multiple implementations, but mostly, it boils down to a `while` loop that keeps doing things repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to add a loop with a keep_running() type check to allow you to break out of the loop. Also, generally a good idea to have a way to issue a reconnect to refresh connections (after n number of messages and/or time period).

psuedo-code:

```
while keep_running():
  // check if we need to setup or reset connection & register listener
  sleep(0.2) // make this short 

// disconnect
```

keep_running()

```
def keep_running():

// some reasons to return 'false'
   return False

// else 
   return True
```

ref: [STOMP Python library](http://jasonrbriggs.github.io/stomp.py/quickstart.html#stomp-py-api)

Comment: I understand that you wrote it as psuedo-code, but `do while` is not valid Python. With them being new to Python, it would probably confused them even more

Comment: @Wondercricket fair enough.  Fixed it up to be closer to python-y

Comment: @JustinBertram updated to more clearly indicate intent-- setup and/or reset connection